# Ui draggable overlay

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

**I need that at the back droppable container would not react if you put dragable on the one which is on the top.** http://jsfiddle.net/rA4CB/161/

Hy guys I have been working on a project for some time already and I just now sow this problem and it is realy killing whole project. I cant change structure of this so I was wondering maybe you guys know any "magic trick" to fix this issue.

```
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p>Drag me to my target</p>
</div>

<div class="droppable" class="ui-widget-header droppable">
    <p>Drop here</p>
</div>
<div class="droppable2" class="ui-widget-header droppable">
    <p>Drop here</p>
</div>
$(function() {


$("#draggable").draggable();
  $(".droppable,.droppable2").droppable({
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this)
        .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
        .find("p")
        .html("Dropped!");
    }
  });
});
```

**extra info:** droppable and droppable2 have to work even z-index will be changed. For example droppable is on the top of droppable2 or opposite. Here you can see z-index problem with 2 droppable functions instead of one. [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/wppykb9a/2/)

Any help would be great !!! thanks in advance.

Comment: your mean is when put `draggable` on the `.droppable2` so `droppable` inner text don't change? @Deividas

Comment: if I Understand right just remove and  change to `$(".droppable2")...`

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **over** and **out** event on the top one to disable the one on the back. Something like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#draggable").draggable();
  $(".droppable").droppable({
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this)
        .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
        .find("p")
        .html("Dropped!");
    }
  });
  $(".droppable2").droppable({
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this)
        .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
        .find("p")
        .html("Dropped!");
    },
    over: function(event, ui) {
      $(".droppable").droppable("disable")
    },
    out: function(event, ui) {
      $(".droppable").droppable("enable")
    }
  });
});
```

Note that if you don't want visual feedback on disable, you'll need to change the CSS for disabled-state.

http://jsfiddle.net/wppykb9a/2/

If you want it to work with **z-index**, it's a bit more complex, but one method you could use is **document.elementFromPoint()**. It returns the top most element at a specific point, so on drop you can put the draggable behind, then check which droppable is the highest at the drop point. Like this:

```
$(function() {
  window.a = 10;

  $(".droppable,.droppable2").draggable();

  $("#draggable").draggable({
    tolerance: 'pointer'
  });
  $(".droppable").droppable({
    accept: "#draggable",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var temp = ui.draggable.zIndex();
        ui.draggable.css('z-index', -1000);
        var topDroppable = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
      ui.draggable.css('z-index', temp);
      $(topDroppable)
        .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
        .find("p")
        .html("Dropped!");
    }
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/17xn0zvz/

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this isnt working if both droppable can be draged and theyr z index is changeing on drag (the one you are draging have to be always on the top) so in this case if droppable and droppable 2 exhange theyr z index it will not work. The problem you can see here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/wppykb9a/24/)

Comment: you can use document.elementFromPoint, it should work. See example in my edit.